# Value of ADX indicator sometimes changes without any reason! Data change?

Tags: server, price, mql4, adx

I am a quite experienced MQL4 programmer and I've written plenty of EAs but this thing is something I just cannot explain..

I have created an EA that uses the following indicator:

iADX(NULL,PERIOD_H1,14,PRICE_OPEN,MODE_MAIN,Shift)

Let's say that the indicator has the following prices for the candle 0 (now) and is 23 (hypothetically).

When the hour passes and the candles change, the 0 candle becomes 1. That means that the indicator's price should be 23 at the candle 1.

Well sometimes it is but some other times it isn't! Sometimes the price of the indicator even changes during the hour as well even before the candle changes.

What would be the reason for this? Is it possible that MT4 gets new data from another server so the candles change thus the indicator's price? Is it a flaw in the system or can it be that MT4 has a bug?

I hope you understood my question. Thank you in advance.

I have tried to save the indicator's price for the 0 candle and after 4 hours when the 0 becomes 5 I look back and see that sometimes the price has changed!